# How to create one KML per polygon (from one Shapefile)?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, polygon, kml, arcgis-9.3

I have a shapefile containing hundreds of polygons. I need to create a kml of each of the polygon. Is there any way that I may not have to deal each polygon individually and my polygon file may give me individual kml of each polygon.

I'm using ArcGIS 9.3 or QGIS.

Comment: You will probably have to write a Python script.  Why do you want an individual KML file per feature?

Comment: Do you want a vector or raster kml?

Comment: actually I have mapped features individually and formed one file for all of them... I have all of the features placed individually but creating their kml in a single go will save my hours... :) I am not familier with python or any other programming language at all... thx a lot for ur help... :)

Comment: I have vector data... :)

Answer (score 1):

With an arcpy.SearchCursor go through your shape file and for each row, append the let's say OBJECTID to a python list.
Now loop through that list and for every entry, create a table view on your shape file with the list entry as query condition. Now I am not sure but I think you need the arcpy.LayerToKML_conversion function. Hopefully you can use the table view as an input for this function, otherwise I think you will need to create temporary shapefiles for each view and use them as input for arcpy.LayerToKML_conversion.

LayerToKML_conversion :
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00120000004n000000

I hope these functions are available in 9.3!

Answer (score 1):

If you want full control, here's a script to convert shapefile polygons to kml, I've just been piping the output of the script to a file, windows: c:\script.py > c:\output.kml. The script also creates a popup and link to a url. If you want separate files, you'll need to open, write to, and close a file on each iteration. Something to start with...Have fun!

```
import arcpy
import sys

class CursorManager:
    def __init__(self, *cursors):
        self.cursors = cursors

    def __enter__(self):
        pass

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        for cur in self.cursors:
            del cur

class CentroidLabel:
    def __init__(self, label, pos, large, extent):
        self.label  = label
        self.pos    = pos
        self.large  = large
        self.extent = extent

#change these paths and file names to appropriate feature classes
fc_arterial = sys.path[0] + r"\arterials_nad83.shp"

#change string substitution into this pdf_link_template to appropriate string
pdf_link_template = """http://YOURSERVER/maplinks/%s/"""

info_popup_template = """<![CDATA[<div style="margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;">%s</div>]]>"""

grid_poly_template = """    <Placemark>
      <name><![CDATA[<span style="font-size:24px">%s</span>]]></name>
      <styleUrl>#%s</styleUrl>
      <description>%s</description>
      <MultiGeometry>
        <Polygon>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <extrude>0</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
        <LinearRing>
           <coordinates>%s</coordinates>
        </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
        </Polygon>
      </MultiGeometry>
    </Placemark>"""

label_point_template = """    <Placemark>
      <name>%s</name>
      <styleUrl>#%s</styleUrl>
      <Point>
        <coordinates> %f,%f </coordinates>
      </Point>
      <Region> 
        <LatLonAltBox> 
          <north>%f</north>
          <south>%f</south>
          <east>%f</east>
          <west>%f</west>
        </LatLonAltBox> 
        <Lod>
          <minLodPixels>%d</minLodPixels>
        </Lod>
      </Region>
    </Placemark>"""

#start creation of kml
print """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document id="crsmaps">
  <name>CRS Maps</name>
  <Snippet></Snippet>"""

print """  <Folder id="arterial">
    <name>Arterial</name>
    <Snippet></Snippet>"""
print """  <Folder id="arterial_grid">
    <name>Grid</name>
    <Snippet></Snippet>"""

#process arterial grid feature class
centroids = []
inCur = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc_arterial)
with CursorManager(inCur):
    for row in inCur:
        poly = row.Shape        
        path = poly.getPart(0)
        outer_cell = row.ARTERIAL
        file_dir  = pdf_link_template % outer_cell.lower()

        if (outer_cell != None and outer_cell.strip() != ""):
            outer_link = file_dir + "%s.pdf" % outer_cell.lower()
            centroid = CentroidLabel(outer_cell, poly.trueCentroid, False, poly.extent)

            link_text = 'Get Arterial Map <a href="%s">%s</a><br/>' % (outer_link, outer_cell)

        allPoints = []
        for point in path:
            if point != None:
                allPoints.append(point)

        if len(allPoints) > 0 and allPoints[0].X != allPoints[-1].X or allPoints[0].Y != allPoints[-1].Y:
            allPoints.append(allPoints[0])

        if len(allPoints) >= 4:
            coord_str = ""
            firstPt = allPoints[0]
            for i in range(len(allPoints)):
                point = allPoints[i]
                coord_str = coord_str + " %f,%f" % (point.X, point.Y)
                if i > 0 and firstPt.X == point.X and firstPt.Y == point.Y:
                    break

            name = outer_cell
            desc = info_popup_template % link_text
            style = "ag"
            place_str = grid_poly_template % (name, style, desc, coord_str)
            print place_str
            centroids.append(centroid)

print """  </Folder>
  <Folder id="arterial_labels">
    <name>Labels</name>
    <Snippet></Snippet>"""

#Create labels for arterial grid
pixels = 50
style  = "a"
for p in centroids:
    point_str = label_point_template % (p.label, style, p.pos.X, p.pos.Y, p.extent.YMax, p.extent.YMin, p.extent.XMax, p.extent.XMin, pixels)
    print point_str

print """  </Folder>
  </Folder>"""


#create styles - short style names reduce kml size
#a = arterial label style
#ag = arterial polygon grid style
print """  <Style id="a">
    <LabelStyle>
      <color>ff0066ff</color>
      <scale>1.5</scale>
    </LabelStyle>
    <IconStyle><Icon/></IconStyle>
  </Style>
  <Style id="ag">
    <LineStyle>
      <color>ff0066ff</color>
      <width>2</width>
    </LineStyle>
    <PolyStyle>
      <fill>0</fill>
      <outline>1</outline>
    </PolyStyle>
  </Style>
</Document>
</kml>
"""
```

Comment: thx a lot for the help... since i have least background in programming i am unable to make it up... but keeping in view the lengthy code u have written for me ill definately try this out... :) I suppose it wodny effect the precisions of the lines... :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also write a simple python script for OSGeo4W, loop through your features and create a kml for each.  For a model to start from, see page 3 of this pdf: http://www.pygis.de/media/GDAL%20-%20Python%20GIS.pdf